# Show/Hide Child Controls on MouseMove/MouseLeave VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, children, mousemove, mouseleave

Imagine a list where the items had child controls (say, a list of songs with media controls). 
I'd like for the child to show on MouseMove of the parent.

The problem I'm facing is that the MouseLeave event, which hides the child controls, fires when the mouse leaves the parent to go into the children (which is completely understandable).

How would one overcome this?

[image: A bit of a diagram...]

I don't have this problem with the text as I have painted it with graphics. I don't want to paint the children as they will need individual event handlers.

All of the items are added dynamically at runtime.

### EDIT

It appears I am, in fact, getting the issue with the MouseLeave event of the graphics.
At the moment, I have the parent's MouseMove event set the ForeColor to blue and the MouseLeave event setting the colour to white. The textis drawn on paint (I use the ForeColor of the parent when I paint the string). It seems that if I leave the parent via the graphics (the top of the graphics is at 0), the ForeColor remains blue.

## The code

```
Private Sub ListItem_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseLeave
    Me.ForeColor = Me.Parent.ForeColor
    _controls.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub ListItem_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseEnter

    Me.ForeColor = SystemColors.HotTrack

    If _controls Is Nothing Then

        Dim p As New Panel
        With p
            .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(23, 23, 23)
            .Width = Me.Height * 1
            .Height = Me.Height
            .Left = Me.Width - Me.Height
            .Top = 0
            .ForeColor = Me.Parent.ForeColor
            .Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(p)
        _controls = p

    Else
        _controls.Show()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ListItem_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim strLen As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(SongName, Me.Font)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(getTrimmedString(SongName, SongNameMaxWidth), Me.Font, New SolidBrush(Me.ForeColor), New Point(3, (Me.Height / 2) - (strLen.Height / 2)))
End Sub
```

Comment: just to clarify, you're doing MouseMove events setting the forecolor instead of MouseEnter for a specific reason?

Comment: I just have always used MouseMove. I'm not too sure why. I just tried it with MouseEnter and it has fixed the MouseLeave event for the graphics (They no longer stay blue when exited directly). I am now using MouseEnter

Comment: MouseMove continually fires when you move the mouse over the container. Only really needed if you update something which constantly changes. MouseEnter is one event. Now that you've switched, what issues are you having?

Comment: Still the same issues as originally stated. The child disappears when you try to hover on it. The MouseLeave event is firing when mouse leaves the parent (to enter the child). If you have Windows 8, I want the same functionality as the mail app...when you hover over a mail list item, three icons appear

Comment: I am thinking that seeing some code rather than screen snaps might clarify what you are doing as well as what is wrong

Comment: Updated the original question with the code

Comment: So you will have multiple listitems, but only create 1 panel which will act as the "child" for all. I assume there's space (the form) between the List control and the child panel, yes? One way would be to trigger a timed event on MouseLeave which is cancelled on MouseEnter of the the child. If it's not cancelled, it hides the child.

Comment: The code is taken from a class, of which there are many instances. Each list item will have their own panel. The panel is generated on MouseEnter as to not create any that aren't needed. The panel (child) will eventually hold multiple controls. Your method will work but I'm not sure yet whether it's the best solution...I'll have to wait and see what knowledge other have to share. I will, however, implement your method until/unless there's a better solution. Thank you:)

Comment: I have since tried to implement the timer idea but I haven't had much luck so other suggestions would be appreciated:)